# GCC still generates guard variables with -fno-threadsafe-statics

Tags: c++, g++, thread-safety, avr-gcc

Below is a simple example using a static member inside a template. If this is compiled with g++ / avr-g++ using the -fno-threadsafe-statics option, the compiler still generates guard variables. This is unnecessary in my opinion.

```
struct A {
    A() {}
    void foo() {}
};

template<typename T>
struct B {
    static void foo() {
        mTop.foo();
    }
    inline static T mTop;
};

int main() {
    B<A>::foo();
}
```

Does anybody know how to disable the generation of an 8-Bytes guard variable?

Edit: if you remove the empty ctor (or a defaulted-ctor) in order to use the compiler-generated, no guards are created. And if you simple create a global variable of type `A` (should be conceptually equal to the above), also no guards are created.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fno-threadsafe-statics), emphasis mine:

> `-fno-threadsafe-statics`
>   Do not emit the extra code to use the routines specified in the C++ ABI for thread-safe initialization **of local statics**. You can use this option to reduce code size slightly in code that doesn’t need to be thread-safe.

The example program in the question doesn't *have* any local `static`s, so there's nothing for this flag to actually apply to. However, even if thread safety isn't necessary, statics do still need a guard variable so as to avoid multiple initialization. Can't get around that.

Comment: Yes, only local statics should need the guards. Here the static should be initialized by the startup code. The strange thing here is, that if you remove the defaulted-ctor of type `A`, so the compiler generated kicks in, then no guards a created. And even stranger, if generate a single global Variable of type A, no guards a created.

Comment: I ran into the same problem again: for a static class member, guards are generated, for static global data not. What's the difference?